# Two way binding failed with nested Objects

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am trying to implement [two way binding on nested Objects](http://jsfiddle.net/k8GkK/23/) and below is my template

```
 {{#with referNames(names, active, contacts)}}
 <!-- also tried {{#with names[contacts[active].names[contacts[active].active]]}} -->
    {{name}}
    <input value="{{active.data}}" />
    <input type="button" value="clone active" on-click="clone" />
 {{/with}}
```

And below is my Data structure

```
{
   contacts : {
      one : {
        active : 0,
        names : ["Name1"] // Keys of names Object (Collection of All names)
      }, two : {
        active : 0,
        names : ["Name2"]
      }
   },
   names : { // Collection of All names
      Name1 : {
        name : "abc",
        active : {
            data : "Name1's data 1"
        }
      }, 
      Name2 : {
        name : "def",
        active : {
            data : "Name2's data 1"
        }
      }
   },
   active : "one",
   referNames : function(names, active, contacts){
      return names[contacts[active].names[contacts[active].active]];
   }
}
```

And the JS code,

```
var r = new Ractive({
   template : "#template",
   el : document.body,
   data : data
});

r.on('clone', function() {
   var t = this, active = t.get('active'), 
    contacts = t.get('contacts.' + active),
    current = contacts.names[contacts.active],
    clone = t.get('names.' + current),
    someId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

   t.set('names.' + someId, clone);
   t.unshift('contacts.' + active + '.names', someId);
   console.log(t.get('contacts'));
   console.log(t.get('names'));
});
```

Expected behaviour is, whenever names array or active value inside contacts changed, textbox value and name also should be updated. Currently it clones the current and appends to the respective names and contacts, but not updated in DOM.

**What I am trying to do is**

In the data object, `active` property is active key to be used from `contacts` object keys. In example as it is "one", that means `contacts.one`, so the value is

```
{ active : 0, names : ["Name1"] }
```

In the above object, key `names` are available name values for that contact and `active` is an index of  name from names to be used. It will be calculated as

```
active // one <global context>
names // data for each name value, <global context>
contacts[active] // contact.one
contacts[active].names // Available names for contact.one, so ["Name1", "Name2" etc..]
contacts[active].active // Index of name to be used in available names, in example its 0 
contacts[active].names[  contacts[active].active ] // Will be "Name1"
names["Name1"] // Name1 from above line
```

finally the referring data would be

```
  Name1 : {
     name : "abc",
     active : {
        data : "Name1's data 1"
     }
  }
```

Hope this is clear and please let me know how can I fix this to dynamically change referenced data on change of active.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm completely lost trying to understand this example! My brain can't even begin to process the line `return names[contacts[active].names[contacts[active].active]]` - as a starting point, I would to to make the code much simpler so that it's possible to see what's going on. Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @RichHarris Thanks for the reply. I have added what I am trying to do. Please check that.

Comment: I'm still very unclear on what the expected behaviour is, and how the result differs from it. Can you describe the exact steps you take to reproduce the problem, and what is supposed to be happening? It may help to simplify your data structure - can more than one contact share the same name ID (e.g. `Name1` etc)? If not, it may make sense to keep the data within the contact itself, rather than referring to it indirectly. Also, I'd avoid reusing property names (like `name`/`names` and `active`) to mean subtly different things at different times.